# Confusion regarding Flask & importing modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, flask

I have a flask app that i'm trying to organize and follow the proper flask folder structure and module/importing that's been shown in many tutorials.

I'm at the point where I actually do not know **why** i'm doing certain things, and that's never a good thing.

My flask app is laid out as follows:

```
/steam
    run.py
    /steamapp
        __init__.py
        config.py
        tasks.py
        views.py
        /static
           css.css
        /templates
           template.html
```

## run.py

```
from steamapp import app
app.run()
```

## **init**.py

```
from celery import Celery
from config import secrets, constants
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
from flask import Flask
import praw

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


app = Flask(__name__)
oid = OpenID(app)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = secrets.APP_SECRET_KEY
celery = make_celery(app)


reddit = praw.Reddit(constants.USERAGENT)
reddit.login(constants.USERNAME, secrets.PASSWORD)

rs = praw.Reddit(constants.USERAGENT)
rs.set_oauth_app_info(secrets.CLIENT_ID, secrets.CLIENT_SECRET, constants.REDIRECT_URL)


from steamapp import views
from steamapp import tasks
```

## views.py

```
from steamapp import app, oid, celery
from tasks import get_auth_url, check_reddit_oauth, request_steam_api
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, request, render_template, url_for
from config import secrets, constants
from flask.ext.openid import OpenID
import os
import praw
import time
import json
import string
import random
import requests


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def check_session_id(session):
    if "id" in session:
        return True
    else:
        return render_template("error.html", error=["?", "No session ID found."])


@app.route("/register")
def register():
    if "id" not in session:
        session["id"] = id_generator()
    authorize_url = get_auth_url(session)
    return redirect(authorize_url)


@app.route("/redirect/")
@oid.loginhandler
def redirect_to_steam_oauth():
   ...
   ...
   ...
   etc
```

## tasks.py

```
from steamapp import celery, rs
from config import secrets, constants
import requests

@celery.task
def get_auth_url(session):
    return rs.get_authorize_url(session["id"], scope="identity")
```

When I run run.py I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/Desktop/Python Projects/Finished/steam/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from steamapp import app
  File "/home/andy/Desktop/Python Projects/Finished/steam/steamapp/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from steamapp import views
  File "/home/andy/Desktop/Python Projects/Finished/steam/steamapp/views.py", line 20, in <module>
    @app.route("/register")
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

I am having trouble understanding what is going on as a whole - I need an explanation for why i'm doing the things i'm doing:

1. What is reason for seperating out `app.run()` into a seperate python file that imports app from steamapp? Why is the app.run() not in views.py?
2. What is **init**.py actually meant to do? Why are the `views.py` and `tasks.py` imported into it?
3. Why is it giving the traceback of "app" not being defined when it's being imported from `__init__.py`?

Thank you to anyone who could provide some clarification, as I have lost the sense of what is going on.

---

## EDIT:

I've updated the code in the OP with changes i've made after reading @dreamriver's response.

I'm still a bit confused - why am I importing flask in views.py when it is already imported in **init**.py, where views is imported and presumably ran from?

Also, how does a celery worker tie into this? Setting tasks.py as a Celery worker returns the following traceback:

```
 celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 769, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 465, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 485, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 229, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 488, in symbol_by_name
    return symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 92, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/andy/Desktop/Python Projects/Finished/steam/steamapp/tasks.py", line 1, in <module>
    from steamapp import celery, rs
ImportError: No module named steamapp
```

Comment: Can you show views.py?

Comment: Done - I've updated the code following @dreamweavers response, but there are some new questions I'm unsure of. (Should I make a new SO post asking about the celery question?)

Comment: On the first issue -- are you confused about why you are importing app into views.py or why you are importing views into ``__init__.py``? Regardless I will update my answer for both now.

Comment: @AndyB i've edit my response to answer all your questions, does that all make sense?

Comment: Thanks @dreamriver, you really helped clear a lot of the confusion i've been having - i'm not entirely 100% on it but it's certainly given me a place to move on from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to explicitly import app into your views file. The error says that app is not defined in views.py, that's because you need to do:

```
from steamapp import app
```

at the top of your views file.

The `__init__.py` turns your directory into a python package. At interpreter startup all the directories that are on $PYTHONPATH with `__init__.py` are added to `sys.path` which makes them importable. `__init__.py` is also executed when the module it defines is imported. This makes it extremely useful for e.g. exporting the main apis of your code. If you looked at the source code for flask you would see that all of the code that you do

```
from flask import Flask, request etc
```

is actually defined in smaller chunks of functionality in separate files and the interesting pieces are then exposed in `__init__.py`.

As said [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) Python doesn't want modules in packages to be the startup file. Python packaging is a bit of a mess. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) stackoverflow answer helped me understand some of these questions, namely that relative imports break completely since they are calculated with respect `__name__` which is set to `'__main__'` when you execute the file directly but the filename itself when it is used via import.

Aside from a few module level globals like `__name__` and `__package__` nothing is explicitly imported into the top level namespace. That's why `app` isn't available to you in your views.py file implicitly.

Does that answer your questions?

### EDIT

You need to import views.py into `__init__.py` because otherwise your views.py file won't get executed and none of your routes and such will be defined. You need to import app into views.py because app isn't in the namespace that your views.py file is able to access. This pattern where two files import each other is called a circular import and can be tricky but it's fine here. You should know that after a module is loaded it gets cached so it doesn't get re-executed when it is imported again.

Your celery problem looks to me that python doesn't see your app on `sys.path` when celery is started. Showing the output of `sys.path` at that point would be helpful. My guess is if you add your working directory to $PYTHONPATH the issue will be fixed. When you install things with pip and the like the packages are added to a place where python knows how to find them by default.

Comment: I'm still fairly confused on the specifics of *why* i'm doing certain things, but I do now understand somewhat how the structure works. I've updated the OP with two questions that I can't figure out the answer to.